# Toggle UITableViewCell in UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView with some cells, where (for example) the first cell is a header, and the second cell contains a View.
I'd like to toggle the view's visibility when I press the header.
The press thingy is done in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, so can I set the visibility of another row from my UITableView (animated if possible)?

Can't find anything about it on Google..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I get the contentView of my UITableViewCell, and change the height of that view.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the table and toggle the row count.

Answer (score 0):

Sure if you know which cell you want to toggle then you can either get a hold of it with cellForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView, or if you just want to reload the cell you can use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: here is a [ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I simply want to make a row invisible, and I do know which cell it is (since I know the index and can retrieve a cell from the tableview with the index). 
Do you have any code example?